# Xamarin System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

im having a hard time with this error and my deadline there is something wrong with my XAML or ViewModel but i cant identify the problem (in new in xamarin).

I keep getting this error `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'` at SignUpView.xaml.g.cs:26

SignUpView.Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:MiniPOS.UserControls;assembly=MiniPOS"
             xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:MiniPOS.Effects;assembly=MiniPOS"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MiniPOS.Views;assembly=MiniPOS"
             xmlns:inputLayout="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.TextInputLayout;assembly=Syncfusion.Core.XForms"
             xmlns:combobox="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.ComboBox;assembly=Syncfusion.SfComboBox.XForms"
             xmlns:border="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.Border;assembly=Syncfusion.Core.XForms"
             xmlns:button="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.Buttons;assembly=Syncfusion.Buttons.XForms"
             xmlns:customViews="clr-namespace:MiniPOS.UserControls;assembly=MiniPOS"
             xmlns:viewModelBase="clr-namespace:MiniPOS.ViewModels.Base;assembly=MiniPOS"
             xmlns:texts="clr-namespace:MiniPOS.Resources.Texts;assembly=MiniPOS"
             viewModelBase:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="true"
             xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             Title="Sign Up"
             x:Name="signUpView"
             x:Class="MiniPOS.Views.SignUpView"
            >
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <Style x:Key="TitleLabelStyle" 
                   TargetType="Label"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource SpectralRegularLabelStyle}">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" 
                        Value="{StaticResource BlueColor}" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" 
                        Value="FillAndExpand" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" 
                        Value="{StaticResource LittleSize}" />
                <Setter Property="Margin"
                        Value="0,10,0,0">
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="AddCustomerHeaderStyle" 
                   TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                        Value="{StaticResource NunitoRegular}" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize"
                        Value="{StaticResource MidMediumSize}" />
                <!--<Setter Property="TextColor"
                        Value="Gray" />-->
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions"
                        Value="FillAndExpand" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions"
                        Value="End" />
                <Setter Property="Margin"
                        Value="0,0,0,0" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="AddCustomerLabelStyle" 
                   TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                        Value="{StaticResource NunitoRegular}" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize"
                        Value="{StaticResource LargeSize}" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor"
                        Value="{StaticResource BlackTextColor}" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions"
                        Value="FillAndExpand" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions"
                        Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Margin"
                        Value="0,10,0,0" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem 
            Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"
            Command="{Binding User_SaveCommand}"
            Text="{texts:Translate Save}"
            Order="Primary"
            Priority="1">
            <ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="Android" Value="save.png" />
                </OnPlatform>
            </ToolbarItem.Icon>
        </ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
                    <Grid Margin="10,15,10,15">
                        <Grid.RowSpacing>
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Android="-5" iOS="10"/>
                        </Grid.RowSpacing>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout Grid.Row="0"
                                                       ContainerType="Outlined"
                                                       FocusedColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                                                       Hint="Username"
                                                       ContainerBackgroundColor="Aqua"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                                       LeadingViewPosition="Inside">
                            <Entry  MaxLength="250" Text="{Binding Username}"/>
                            <inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout.LeadingView>
                                <Label FontSize="18" 
                                               Text="&#xf3c5;"
                                               TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                                    <Label.FontFamily>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="Font Awesome 5 Free" Android="fa-solid-900.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid" >
                                        </OnPlatform>
                                    </Label.FontFamily>
                                </Label>
                            </inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout.LeadingView>
                        </inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout>
                        <inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout Grid.Row="1"
                                                       ContainerType="Outlined"
                                                       FocusedColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                                                       ContainerBackgroundColor="Aqua"
                                                       Hint="Password"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                                       LeadingViewPosition="Inside">
                            <Entry IsPassword="True" MaxLength="250" Text="{Binding Password}"/>
                            <inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout.LeadingView>
                                <Label FontSize="18" 
                                               Text="&#xf3c5;"
                                               TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                                    <Label.FontFamily>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="Font Awesome 5 Free" Android="fa-solid-900.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid" >
                                        </OnPlatform>
                                    </Label.FontFamily>
                                </Label>
                            </inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout.LeadingView>
                        </inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout>
                        <inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout Grid.Row="2"
                                                       ContainerType="Outlined"
                                                       FocusedColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                                                       Hint="First Name"
                                                       ContainerBackgroundColor="Aqua"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                                       LeadingViewPosition="Inside">
                            <Entry  MaxLength="250" Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                            <inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout.LeadingView>
                                <Label FontSize="18" 
                                               Text="&#xf3c5;"
                                               TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                                    <Label.FontFamily>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="Font Awesome 5 Free" Android="fa-solid-900.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid" >
                                        </OnPlatform>
                                    </Label.FontFamily>
                                </Label>
                            </inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout.LeadingView>
                        </inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout>
                        <inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout Grid.Row="3"
                                                       ContainerType="Outlined"
                                                       FocusedColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                                                       ContainerBackgroundColor="Aqua"
                                                       Hint="Last Name"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                                       LeadingViewPosition="Inside">
                            <Entry  MaxLength="250" Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                            <inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout.LeadingView>
                                <Label FontSize="18" 
                                               Text="&#xf3c5;"
                                               TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                                    <Label.FontFamily>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="Font Awesome 5 Free" Android="fa-solid-900.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid" >
                                        </OnPlatform>
                                    </Label.FontFamily>
                                </Label>
                            </inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout.LeadingView>
                        </inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout>
                        <inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout Grid.Row="4"
                                                       ContainerType="Outlined"
                                                       FocusedColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                                                       ContainerBackgroundColor="Aqua"
                                                       HasError="{Binding IsMobileInValid}"
                                                       Hint="{texts:Translate PhoneHint}"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                                       LeadingViewPosition="Inside">
                            <Entry Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}" Keyboard="Telephone"/>
                            <inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout.LeadingView>
                                <Label FontSize="18" 
                                               Text="&#xf3cd;"
                                               TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                                    <Label.FontFamily>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="Font Awesome 5 Free" Android="fa-solid-900.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid" >
                                        </OnPlatform>
                                    </Label.FontFamily>
                                </Label>
                            </inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout.LeadingView>
                        </inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout>

                        <inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout Grid.Row="5"
                                                       ContainerType="Outlined"
                                                       FocusedColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                                                       ContainerBackgroundColor="Aqua"
                                                       HasError="{Binding IsEmailInValid}"
                                                       Hint="Email"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                                       LeadingViewPosition="Inside">
                            <Entry Text="{Binding Email}" Keyboard="Email"/>
                            <inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout.LeadingView>
                                <Label FontSize="18" 
                                               Text="&#xf0e0;"
                                               TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                                    <Label.FontFamily>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="Font Awesome 5 Free" Android="fa-solid-900.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid" >
                                        </OnPlatform>
                                    </Label.FontFamily>
                                </Label>
                            </inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout.LeadingView>
                        </inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout>

                        <inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout Grid.Row="6"
                                                       ContainerType="Outlined"
                                                       FocusedColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                                                       ContainerBackgroundColor="Aqua"
                                                       Hint="{texts:Translate AddressHint}"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                                       LeadingViewPosition="Inside">
                            <Entry Text="{Binding Address}" MaxLength="250"/>
                            <inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout.LeadingView>
                                <Label FontSize="18" 
                                               Text="&#xf3c5;"
                                               TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                                    <Label.FontFamily>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="Font Awesome 5 Free" Android="fa-solid-900.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid" >
                                        </OnPlatform>
                                    </Label.FontFamily>
                                </Label>
                            </inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout.LeadingView>
                        </inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <customViews:LoadingIndicator 
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                        VerticalOptions="Fill" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

SignUpView.Xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MiniPOS.ViewModels;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MiniPOS.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SignUpView : ContentPage
    {
        public SignUpViewModel Context => (SignUpViewModel)this.BindingContext;
        public SignUpView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
        }
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            App.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
        }



        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            App.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Pan);
        }

        private void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((SignUpViewModel)this.BindingContext).User_SaveCommand.Execute(null);
            Navigation.RemovePage(this);
        }
```

SignUpViewModel.cs

```
using DataModel;
using MiniPOS.AppSettings;
using MiniPOS.Entity;
using MiniPOS.Extensions;
using MiniPOS.Helpers;
using MiniPOS.Resources.Texts;
using MiniPOS.Services;
using MiniPOS.ViewModels.Base;
using MiniPOS.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace MiniPOS.ViewModels
{
    public class SignUpViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly ISignUpService _signUpService;
        private User _user;
        private List<User> _users;
        private UserDetail _userDetail;
        private readonly LogWriter log = new LogWriter();
        const string filename = "SignUpViewModel.cs";
        public SignUpViewModel(ISignUpService signUpService)
        {
            _signUpService = signUpService;
            _user = new User();
            _userDetail = new UserDetail();
            _users = new List<User>();
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this, "OnDataSourceChanged", (args) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    IsBusy = true;
                    await LoadSignUp();
                    IsBusy = false;
                    ItemIndex = -1;
                });
            });
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await LoadSignUp();
            });
        }
        public List<User> Users
        {
            get => _users;
            set
            {
                _users = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Users);
            }
        }
        public async Task LoadSignUp()
        {
            Expression<Func<User, bool>> signUpExpression = x => x.Deleted == 0;
            var cashs = await _signUpService.GetAllUserAsync(signUpExpression);
        }
        private string _username;
        public string Username
        {
            get => _username;
            set
            {
                _username = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Username);
            }
        }

        private string _password;
        public string Password
        {
            get => _password;
            set
            {
                _password = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Password);
            }
        }

        private string _firstName;
        public string FirstName
        {
            get => _firstName;
            set
            {
                _firstName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => FirstName);
            }
        }

        private string _lastName;
        public string LastName
        {
            get => _lastName;
            set
            {
                _lastName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => LastName);
            }
        }

        private long _phoneNumber;
        public long PhoneNumber
        {
            get => _phoneNumber;
            set
            {
                _phoneNumber = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => PhoneNumber);
            }
        }

        private string _email;
        public string Email
        {
            get => _email;
            set
            {
                _email = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Email);
            }
        }

        private string _address;
        public string Address
        {
            get => _address;
            set
            {
                _address = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Address);
            }
        }

        private void ResetForm()
        {
            Username = string.Empty;
            Password = string.Empty;
            PhoneNumber = 0;
            Email = string.Empty;
            Address = string.Empty;
            FirstName = string.Empty;
            LastName = string.Empty;
        }

        public ICommand User_SaveCommand => new Command(async () => await AddUser_SaveAsync());

        public async Task AddUser_SaveAsync()
        {
            string informedMessage = "";
            IsBusy = true;
            var user = new User
            {
                Id = Generator.GenerateKey(),
                Username = Username,
                Password = Password,
                IsSuper = true
            };
            await _signUpService.InsertUserAsync(user);
            var userDetail = new UserDetail
            {
                Id = Generator.GenerateKey(),
                UserId = user.Id,
                FirstName = FirstName,
                LastName = LastName,
                Email = Email,
                Address = Address,
                PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber,
                Role = 0,
                IsSync = false
            };
            await _signUpService.InsertUserDetailAsync(userDetail);
            ResetForm();
            informedMessage = TextsTranslateManager.Translate("CustomerSaved");
            log.Info("User Saved", filename);
            App._uValid = false;
            IsBusy = false;
            DialogService.ShowToast(informedMessage);
        }
        private void ConvertBackModelToEntity()
        {
            _user.Username = Username;
            _user.Password = Password;
            _userDetail.FirstName = FirstName;
            _userDetail.LastName = LastName;
            _userDetail.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
            _userDetail.Address = Address;
            _userDetail.Email = Email;
        }

        public override async Task InitializeAsync(object navigationData)
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            PageTitle = TextsTranslateManager.Translate("AddCustomerTitle");
            IsBusy = false;
        }


    }
}
```

i notice in other questions is that normaly is a issue in the xaml but i cant find my error (sorry for bad english)

Output:

```
**System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:** 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

02-20 16:41:34.738 E/mono    (20824): 
02-20 16:41:34.738 E/mono    (20824): Unhandled Exception:
02-20 16:41:34.738 E/mono    (20824): System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> TinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: MiniPOS.ViewModels.SignUpViewModel ---> TinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: MiniPOS.ViewModels.SignUpViewModel ---> TinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: MiniPOS.Services.ISignUpService
02-20 16:41:34.738 E/mono    (20824):   at TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration, TinyIoC.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, TinyIoC.ResolveOptions options) [0x0022c] in C:\Users\Juan Finol\source\repos\terminalpointofsale\Mobile\MiniPOS\MiniPOS\TinyIoC\TinyIoC.cs:3827 
02-20 16:41:34.738 E/mono    (20824):   at TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, TinyIoC.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, TinyIoC.ResolveOptions options) [0x000ab] in C:\Users\Juan Finol\source\repos\terminalpointofsale\Mobile\MiniPOS\MiniPOS\TinyIoC\TinyIoC.cs:4031 
02-20 16:41:34.738 E/mono    (20824):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
02-20 16:41:34.738 E/mono    (20824):   at TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, TinyIoC.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, TinyIoC.ResolveOptions options) [0x000ee] in C:\Users\Juan Finol\source\repos\terminalpointofsale\Mobile\MiniPOS\MiniPOS\TinyIoC\TinyIoC.cs:4043 
02-20 16:41:34.738 E/mono    (20824):   at TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer+MultiInstanceFactory.GetObject (System.Type requestedType, TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer container, TinyIoC.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, TinyIoC.ResolveOptions options) [0x00002] in C:\Users\Juan Finol\source\repos\terminalpointofsale\Mobile\MiniPOS\MiniPOS\TinyIoC\TinyIoC.cs:2858 
02-20 16:41:34.738 E/mono    (20824):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
02-20 16:41:34.738 E/mono    (20824):   at TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer+MultiInstanceFactory.GetObject (System.Type requestedType, TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer container, TinyIoC.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, TinyIoC.ResolveOptions options) [0x0001d] in C:\Users\Juan Finol\source\repos\terminalpointofsale\Mobile\MiniPOS\MiniPOS\TinyIoC\TinyIoC.cs:2862 
02-20 16:41:34.738 E/mono    (20824):   at TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration, TinyIoC.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, TinyIoC.ResolveOptions options) [0x0002d] in C:\Users\Juan Finol\source\repos\terminalpointofsale\Mobile\MiniPOS\MiniPOS\TinyIoC\TinyIoC.cs:3736 
02-20 16:41:34.738 E/mono    (20824):   at TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Resolve (System.Type resolveType) [0x00001] in C:\Users\Juan Finol\source\repos\terminalpointofsale\Mobile\MiniPOS\MiniPOS\TinyIoC\TinyIoC.cs:1827 
02-20 16:41:34.739 E/mono    (20824):   at MiniPOS.ViewModels.Base.ViewModelLocator.OnAutoWireViewModelChanged (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object oldValue, System.Object newValue) [0x00070] in C:\Users\Juan Finol\source\repos\terminalpointofsale\Mobile\MiniPOS\MiniPOS\ViewModels\Base\ViewModelLocator.cs:158 
02-20 16:41:34.739 E/mono    (20824):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context, System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean silent) [0x00120] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:463 
02-20 16:41:34.739 E/mono    (20824):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) [0x00173] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:397 
02-20 16:41:34.739 E/mono    (20824):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, System.Boolean fromStyle, System.Boolean checkAccess) [0x00042] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:334 
02-20 16:41:34.739 E/mono    (20824):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:311 
02-20 16:41:34.739 E/mono    (20824):   at MiniPOS.Views.SignUpView.InitializeComponent () [0x00023] in C:\Users\Juan Finol\source\repos\terminalpointofsale\Mobile\MiniPOS\MiniPOS\obj\Debug
etstandard2.0\Views\SignUpView.xaml.g.cs:26 
02-20 16:41:34.739 E/mono    (20824):   at MiniPOS.Views.SignUpView..ctor () [0x00008] in C:\Users\Juan Finol\source\repos\terminalpointofsale\Mobile\MiniPOS\MiniPOS\Views\SignUpView.xaml.cs:16 
02-20 16:41:34.739 E/mono    (20824):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
02-20 16:41:34.739 E/mono    (20824):   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/RuntimeMethodInfo.cs:936 
02-20 16:41:34.739 E/mono    (20824):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: what does the InnerException say?

Comment: @Jason i added the output in the question

Comment: "Unable to resolve type: MiniPOS.Services.ISignUpService". Seems pretty clear about the error. I've never used TinyIoC before, but you probably need to register the ISignUpService with the container, something like `_container.Register<ISignUpService, SignUpService>();`

Comment: @Andrew Thank you! that solved my problem!

Comment: You're welcome. I added my comment as an answer and expanded on it slightly. Feel free to mark it as the answer in case anybody else stumbles on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception tells us what the error is:

`Unable to resolve type: MiniPOS.Services.ISignUpService`

In order to inject/resolve the ISignUpService in the constructor, it needs to be registered with the TinyIoC container. This would be something like

```
var container = TinyIoCContainer.Current;
container.Register<ISignUpService, SignUpService>();
```

Note that you would want to do this early in the app lifecycle, probably in the App.Xaml.cs file.

Take a look at the [TinyIoC docs](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC/wiki/Registration---lifetimes#registration--lifetimes) for more information.